# CollectionAction route being skipped, action treated as ID

Tags: activeadmin

I'm trying to create a `collection_action` in ActiveAdmin which allows me to Import a CSV file and generate Subscribers from it. I want to be able to click an `action_item` link and be taken to a form in which I input the CSV file, and then do some work with it.

This is what I have so far:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Subscriber do

collection_action :import_csv, :method => :post do 
    render "import_csv"
end         

action_item do 
    link_to "Import from CSV", import_csv_admin_subscribers_path
end
```

The view is also created, just blank at the moment. I've restarted the rails server, and `rake routes` outputs:

```
import_csv_admin_subscribers POST       /admin/subscribers/import_csv(.:format)       admin/subscribers#import_csv
batch_action_admin_subscribers POST       /admin/subscribers/batch_action(.:format)     admin/subscribers#batch_action
             admin_subscribers GET        /admin/subscribers(.:format)                  admin/subscribers#index
                               POST       /admin/subscribers(.:format)                  admin/subscribers#create
          new_admin_subscriber GET        /admin/subscribers/new(.:format)              admin/subscribers#new
         edit_admin_subscriber GET        /admin/subscribers/:id/edit(.:format)         admin/subscribers#edit
              admin_subscriber GET        /admin/subscribers/:id(.:format)              admin/subscribers#show
                               PUT        /admin/subscribers/:id(.:format)              admin/subscribers#update
                               DELETE     /admin/subscribers/:id(.:format)              admin/subscribers#destroy
```

However when I click the action item I get the error `Couldn't find Subscriber with id=import_csv`

If I change the method to `:get` it renders the view fine. I'm assuming the problem is my use of `:post`? Is it not possible to render a view if you're calling a controller action with that method?

**edit** Ok, yeah, it doesn't make sense to render a view with a `post` but then [why does the ActiveAdmin doc](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#collection_actions) suggest that you do the action this way for CSV imports? How are you supposed to `# Do some CSV importing work here...` without generation a form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the method: :post option to the link to invocation, since there's no get action for that url.